# Casting error using KBCsv to load a datatable

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable

I have an application that was written in VS 2015. It's been running for several years without a problem.
I've upgraded to VS 2019. The code, unchanged, throws an error when trying to load a datatable using the KBCsv library.
The error is "Unable to cast object of type 'KBCsv.CsvReader' to type 'System.Data.IDataReader'."
The code concerned is as follows:

Getting the data from a web service API:

```
            Request = HttpWebRequest.Create(fullurl)
' fullurl is built earlier in the code
            Request.Proxy = Nothing 'speeds up the request
            Request.UserAgent = "Test"
            Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse
            Dim ResponseStream As System.IO.Stream = Response.GetResponseStream
            Dim StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(ResponseStream)
            Dim Data As String = StreamReader.ReadToEnd
            StreamReader.Close()

            ReadfileIntoTable(Data) 'creates RawData table and TrimmedRawData table in PRDataset
```

ReadfileIntoTable:

```
    Private Sub ReadfileIntoTable(DataIn)

        Dim RawDatatable = New System.Data.DataTable("RawDataTable")
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("BookingID", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("StartDate", GetType(Date))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("EndDate", GetType(Date))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("KingSheets", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Vegetarian", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Coeliac", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Spa", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Mobile", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Bookingstatus", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Emailaddress", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Guestnotes", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Room", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("Tariff", GetType(String))
        RawDatatable.Columns.Add("DepartureDate", GetType(Date))

        Dim reader As CsvReader = CsvReader.FromCsvString(DataIn)
        reader.ValueSeparator = ","
        reader.ValueDelimiter = """"

        Try

            Using reader

                reader.ReadHeaderRecord()
                RawDatatable.Load(reader)

            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Couldn't read into RawDataTable " & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

The error occurs in this using block

```
            Using reader

                reader.ReadHeaderRecord()
                RawDatatable.Load(reader)

            End Using
```

Why is this happening, and how do I get around it without rewriting the code for loading the datatable?

Comment: Does that `CsvReader` class implement the `IDataReader` interface? It doesn't appear to, and that is the type of the `DataTable.Load` parameter. The only way I can see that that would have worked is if you were actually calling an extension method named `Load` rather than an actual instance method of the `DataTable` class. I suggest that you go back to the project in VS 2015 and see whether that's the case. If so, you would need to make sure to reference the appropriate assembly and import the appropriate namespace to access that method.

Comment: If that was a run-time exception rather than a compilation error then that indicates that you have `Option Strict Off` for that project. That's bad. You should ALWAYS have `Option Strict On` except in specific cases where you need to use late binding, and then only have `Option Strict Off` in specific files that need it. You should set `Option Strict On` in the VS options so that it is the default for all future projects.

Comment: `Private Sub ReadfileIntoTable(DataIn)`   `DataIn` requires an As Type.

Comment: @Mary, it certainly should have a type and would require one with `Option Strict On`, but it will simply be typed as `Object` and implicitly converted at run time as the code is now.

Comment: Did you try the current version? https://www.nuget.org/packages/KBCsv/

Comment: Isn't `Using reader` essentially DIM'ing a new variable with the same name as the previously declared `Dim reader As CsvReader = CsvReader.FromCsvString(DataIn)`?

Comment: Thank you all for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I had Option Strict Off. I haven't made that mistake since the early days of VBA. Yes, I've tried the latest version of KBCsv. I've also gone back to VS2015, restored the code from tape (yes I'm that old), cranked up another machine and VS environment, and still get the casting error every time. Yet the distributed application continues to run just fine. Short of attempting to decompile, I'll try another approach to loading the datatable.